# Can't connect to the server from the browser

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, serversocket

I've created a client and server,
If I run the client on the Flash player standalone it works great.
but if I run it from my localhost, from my browser (with wamp server) it does not work.
The error (on the server side):

```
Error: Error #2030: End of file was encountered.
at flash.net::Socket/readUTF()
at com.TWW::serverAPI/getData()[FILE:64]
```

line 64 is:

```
var text:String = socket.readUTF();
```

and I don't understand why through the browser it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a socket through the browser, Flash doesn't send right away what you're sending to the server.

First of all, it opens a first connection, and ask the server if it can connect. It sends a `<policy-file-request/>`

The server must answer something like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="YOURLOCALDOMAIN" to-ports="PORT YOUR SERVER IS RUNNING AT" /></cross-domain-policy>
```

Followed by a `NULL` byte.

Then, Flash closes the connection to your server, and if the policy authorize its access, it will open again a "real" connection, that will stay established and on which you can send data.

[More infos here.](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket%5fpolicy%5ffiles.html)

Comment: You need to implement that on the server side. What is the server you're trying to connect on ?

Comment: Its my server, its **socketserver**, actionscript3

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by *blue112*, here is my solution:

```
…
while( (k = in.read(buff, 0, 1)) > -1 ) {
    result += new String(buff, 0, k);

    // Flash privacy policy
    if(result.equals("<policy-file-request/>")) {
        out.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"12345\" /></cross-domain-policy>\0");
        out.flush();
    }

    // Process message stuff
    …
}
…
```